# Generate Getters and Setters in a Koltin Class in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, getter-setter

I am trying to generate Getters and Setters in my Kotlin model class without writing the code manually but the options are not showing up in the Generate Menu in Android Studio.

**My Model Class (Kotlin)**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

public class EventsRoadSummaryAPINodeModel {

    @SerializedName("road_name")
    @Expose
    var road_name: String? = null

    @SerializedName("locality")
    @Expose
    var locality: String? = null

    @SerializedName("postcode")
    @Expose
    var postcode: String? = null

    @SerializedName("local_government_area")
    @Expose
    var local_government_area: String? = null

    @SerializedName("district")
    @Expose
    var district: String? = null
}
```

How do I generate getters and setters in a Kotlin class, please?

Comment: Not sure why the generate Getter Setter options are not showing up in the Generate Menu in Android Studio for Kotlin based code

Comment: A `var` in Kotlin already generates a getter and setter. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to generate ---  fun getType(): String? {
        return type
    }

    fun setType(type: String?) {
        this.type = type
    }

Comment: Yes, that's what you get automatically when you have `var type: String? = null`. You don't have to writer getters and setters for properties.

Comment: Ahh ok, lol just wasted some time, oh well thanks for clarifying. Maybe I should have read more of the Kotlin docs ...

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Kotlin Properties and Fields documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), each mutable (i.e., `var`) property has a getter and setter automatically created for it.

Therefore there's no reason to auto generate getters and setters for Kotlin code.

If you have annotations that need to be put on specifically the generated getter, for instance, you can use the `@get:Expose` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use '**data class**' for the same. in data class, you don't need to make the Getter-Setter method. data class automatically create for you

Kotlin Documentation [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

Check Google Codelab example for same [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#3)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so poor-mans solution was to paste the Kotlin code below into a java file and reformat the variables to java code. Then the option to generate Getters Setters in the Generate menu appears, in which you can process and generate the Getters Setters.

**Temp Java file used to generate Getters Setters**

```
public class EventsRoadSummaryAPINodeModel {

  @SerializedName("road_name")
  @Expose
  String road_name;

  @SerializedName("locality")
  @Expose
  String  locality;

  @SerializedName("postcode")
  @Expose
  String  postcode;

  @SerializedName("local_government_area")
  @Expose
  String  local_government_area;

  @SerializedName("district")
  @Expose
  String  district;

}
```

I then pasted the generate Getters Setters into my orginal Kotlin class file and let android studio reformt the pasted code to Kotlin format.